# exporting local db to azure sql databases

Tags: sql, azure, export, azure-sql-database

This is my first use Azure Sql Databases. 
I have DB on my local and I connect to Azure Sql Database via Management Studio
I want to export my local db to Azure but I get this error message

"Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again"

but table has a Id column as a primary key clustered index.

Local sql server : Sql Server 2012

So what should I do ?

Comment: Can you expand on the steps you took that led you to the error message?

Comment: I use the database->task->export options. But I see another option which is "deploy database sql azure". And I use it and fixed issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sql Server Management Studio has "deploy database sql azure" command under tasks. 
I fixed this issiue by using this